# haystack's RealTimeSearchIndex causes django to hang on data entry

Tags: django, xapian, rhel5, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack and a xapian backend with real time indexing (`haystack.indexes.RealTimeSearchIndexing`) of model data and it works fine on my Ubuntu server. However, it causes django to hang upon data entry when I deployed the app on a RHEL5 server.

Everything is hunky dory if I switch to a standard `SearchIndex`.

Running `./manage.py rebuild_index` manually works fine too.

The major differences between the two setups would be the versions of Python (2.4.3 vs 2.6.4) and the xapian (1.0.4-1 vs 1.0.15).

Any suggestions on what may be the problem?

Nothing interesting appears in the logs, and I've tried different databases (mysql, sqlite3) and deployment methods (mod_python, wsgi) with no luck yet.

I have noted the [warning](http://haystacksearch.org/docs/searchindex_api.html#realtimesearchindex) on the haystack docs stating that `RealTimeSearchIndex` is only handled gracefully with a Solr backend, however I'm running a very low traffic site with only occasional writes so I'm fine with some CPU overheads on writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing xapian-core and xapian-bindings from source solved the problem.

I initially used the RPM packages provided [here](http://xapian.org/download).

Answer (score 1):

Please note this from the author of [xapian-haystack](http://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack):

> Because Xapian does not support simultaneous WritableDatabase connections, it is strongly recommended that users take care when using RealTimeSearchIndex to either set WSGIDaemonProcess processes=1 or use some other way of ensuring that there are not multiple attempts to write to the indexes. Alternatively, use SearchIndex and a cronjob to reindex content at set time intervals (sample cronjob can be found here http://gist.github.com/216247) or derive your own SearchIndex to implement some other form of keeping your indexes up to date.

Comment: Thanks prometheus. I have come across that snippet, unfortunately WSGIDaemonProcess processes=1 does not seem to help in my case. Anyway, +1 for bringing it up. Might help someone else.